# Modern SharePoint List Form Header Json Formatting

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have a SP list form header that works all except one part. I have a calculated column formatted as a number. I want to reference this in the header and use it to pick and color an icon. Here is what my Json looks like but it doesn't seem to recognize the column.

```
    {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "15px",
        "background-color": "RGBA(0,95,131,1)"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "tagsolid",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "10px",
                        "height": "40px",
                        "color": "white"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "color": "white"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=if([$Title]=='','New','Reject Tag Database - Tag #' + [$Title])"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "left"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "=if([$Remaining_x0020_Balance] == 0,'boxcheckmarksolid','boxmultiplysolid')",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "debugMode": true,
                    "txtContent": "@currentField",
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "10px",
                        "padding-top": "20px",
                        "height": "40px",
                        "visibility": "=if([$Title]=='','hidden','visible'",
                        "color": "=if([$Remaining_x0020_Balance] == 0, 'green', 'red')"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "box-sizing": "border-box",
                        "width": "100%",
                        "text-align": "left",
                        "padding": "21px 5px",
                        "overflow": "hidden",
                        "color": "white",
                        "visibility": "=if([$Title]=='','hidden','visible'"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "txtContent": "Closed"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "right",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "color": "white"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=if([$Title]=='','','Part Number : '+[$PartNumber])"
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=if([$Title]=='','','Tag Quantity : '+[$Quantity])"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody see what is wrong and why it is not working? It should read, if Remaining Balance is equal to 0 give green checkmark box, else give red multiply box.

Thanks

EDIT: I have updated the code with the full Json because I'm thinking that is the problem. I'm sure it is a mess where I have just pieced it together bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have test following Json Formatting and works

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if([$Remaining_x0020_Balance] == 0,'boxcheckmarksolid','boxmultiplysolid')",
    "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
    "title": "Details"
  },
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "flex": "none",
    "padding": "0px",
    "padding-left": "10px",
    "height": "40px",
    "color": "=if([$Remaining_x0020_Balance] == 0, 'green', 'red')"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @RatheonXie, This does not seem to work for the header on the form or maybe it's my data? The form header is still showing a red X for items with a 0 in the Remaining balance field for that item. The column is filled with this formula =[Quantity Rejected]-([Quantity Scrap]+[Quantity RTV]+[Quantity Rework]+[Quantity Returned to Use]) and formatted as Number.

Comment: I found if I just add the [$Remaining_x0020_Balance] to the header in place of text it doesn't show anything so I think I'm missing something with the column identification. This is the end of the address bar when I go to edit the column. Field=Remaining_x0020_Balance so I think it's just not seeing the value or something?

Comment: Ok so I think the problem lies somewhere in the Json. I added a column that outputs a Yes/No or True/False and tried to base it off that and it still doesn't work. This makes me think it is from the Json. Any help there from anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this from my end and I am able to reproduce this issue. I think this is a bug while using calculated column in JSON form formatting.

The calculated column value is available in the page context but it is not shown in form header:

[image]

I have raised a new bug/issue here: [JSON Form formatting: Unable to use the calculated column value in header/footer layout customization](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8788). Hopefully Microsoft will fix this in near future.

**Similar thread**: [Get value of Name column from SPO list for JSON formatting in the header](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306211/get-value-of-name-column-from-spo-list-for-json-formatting-in-the-header/306215#306215)

Also, you have to use the **internal name** of your columns in the JSON formatting. You can get the internal name of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)